# How many bits are required to sample an almost pairwise independent hash function?

Tags: hash-function, pseudorandomness

A family of functions $\mathcal{H} = \{ h\colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^m \}$ is said to be *$\varepsilon$-almost pairwise independent* if, for every distinct $x_1,x_2 \in \{0,1\}^n$ and (not necessarily distinct) $y_1$, $y_2 \in \{0,1\}^m$:
$$\left| \Pr\left[h(x_1) = y_1 \land h(x_2) = y_2 \right] - \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\right| \le \varepsilon$$

Although the literature is a bit scarce, there are realiable sources (e.g., [here](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Esalil/pseudorandomness/)) stating that one can sample such a function using $O(m + \log n + \log{(1/\varepsilon)})$ bits. However, I have checked the [original paper by Alon et al.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rsa.3240030308) and I can't seem to wrap my head around why this isn't just $O(\log m + \log n + \log{(1/\varepsilon)})$ bits instead.

---

**My reasoning:** In the paper by Alon et al., the authors construct a so-called *$(\varepsilon, k)$-independent sample space* (see note below). This is a subset $S \subseteq \{0,1\}^\ell$ such that, for any $s_1\cdots s_\ell$ that is sampled according to $S$, any $k$-bit string $\alpha$, and any $i_1 < \cdots < i_k$, we have:
$$\left| \Pr\left[s_{i_1} \cdots s_{i_k} = \alpha \right] - \frac{1}{2^k} \right| \le \varepsilon$$

If I understand correctly, we then get an $\varepsilon$-almost pairwise independent by setting $\ell = 2^n \cdot m$ and $k = 2m$ and identifying $s_1 \cdots s_\ell$ with the obvious description for a hash function $h$ (i.e., $2^n$ many strings, each of length $m$). Then we can use the inequality above by setting (for any $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ as before) $s_{i_1} \cdots s_{i_m} = h(x_1)$, $s_{i_{m+1}} \cdots s_{i_{2m}} = h(x_2)$, and $\alpha = y_1y_2$, in which case we recover the necessary condition for almost pairwise independence.

According to the paper's results, we only need
$$O(\log{(k \log \ell)} + \log{(1/\varepsilon)}) = O(\log m + \log n + \log{(1/\varepsilon))}$$
bits to do so.

This seems to be essentially what is shown in [this other paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-69053-0_28) too (see Proposition 2.3).

---

**My question:** What am I missing?